# An object or column name is missing or empty- issue in SQL server installation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation

I'm installing SQL Server 2012 on my system. I'm getting following error:

[image]

On my system, I had a named instance already installed. I was trying to install one more instance but it failed. I tried with removing all sql components but same issue.

I did some search on same issue and found the following link: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/736753/error-installing-database-engine-services-instance-features-in-sql-server-2012-developer-edition-rtm-an-object-or-column-name-is-missing-or-empty

According to this link, I shouldn't add any user except current user during installation. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Folks, I was installing SQL server using local account on my system. I switched to domain account. uninstalled each sql package from system. And then reinstalled sql server by adding domain account as administrator.  Later i have also added my local account on sql server. Luckily it works :)